# error bars of inline plot coordinates format pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, error-bars

Can somebody please explain to me how to read the error bars from the following?[image]
I get that (1,2) is the coordinate of the point but what does (0.4,0.2) represent? Are 0.4 and 0.2 the error values of x and y, respectively?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! This depends on your settings, see section 4.12 Error Bars of the pgfplots manual. You could have `y dir=plus,y explicit` or `y dir=both,y explicit` or anything. This can be only judged on the basis of a complete compilable example.

Comment: What would be the case for y dir=both ?

Comment: There is a wonderful manual that explains all this. The purpose of this site is to help when there are problems with a code. Unfortunately you only provide a screen shot of a code fragment.

Comment: I can only support @marmot's comment. And as it seems, the image is a screenshot of the manual. So without checking it I guess that surround this example it is explained what it is good for ...